# Sensor supplied by MCU - sink or source what is most energy efficient?

Tags: power-supply, sensor, avr, low-power, hall-effect

I'm building a tiny system for fridge door monitoring. AVR (Attiny13A) is used which is connected to a linear hall sensor OH49E, the complete system is battery powered and I'm trying to minimize power consumption as much as possible. Right now the sensor is powered by a pin from the AVR (+3,6V, 3xAA rechargeables) but there is also a 100nF bypass capacitor connected to the supply of the sensor. The sensor is sourced by the AVR to be able to turn it off completely, saving 4,2 mA.

My concern now is if I should sink the sensor instead of sourcing it. By doing that I will prevent the capacitor to discharge every time the the source pin is going to low state.

So what is the most power efficient way of using an external sensor? Sourcing or sinking it? Or are there other better alternatives?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFfI6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Consider a reed switch which closes when the door is opened, generating an interrupt to wakeup the MCU.  That would have no power consumption when the door is closed and easily less than 300 uA when it is open.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention that a digital hall sensor or switch is not an option. I considered this from the beginning but I need a linear sensor because warning position is set with user input of a button. 
The MCU is put into power-down mode with watchdog timer running waking the MCU every 8th second and read the sensor and goes back to sleep if the door is still closed. I've now been able to lower the current consumption of the complete system to 24 uA in power-down mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the safety of the device, you *cannot* use the "sink" disconnecting the ground could lead to unreliable operation. Further, disconnecting the ground will also *not* prevent the 100nF capacitor from discharging. The OH49E will still load the capacitor and discharge it when the MCU tri-states the CTRL port. Efficiency is only a matter of on time versus off time for the sensor device.

An additional problem is that the OH49E does not have a turn-on specification. It appears to be intended only for constant-supply operation. You will have to determine by testing how long it takes for the output to stabilize for an accurate reading. The suggestion by Chris Stratton in the comment about using interrupts and a reed switch would likely be more efficient because only the low-power MCU would be drawing power. The pull-up resistor for the switch could also be large to have only a small current when the door is opened.

Comment: I was thinking about not tri-state the CTRL port. I thought I could leave it as output and put it HIGH, but maybe that's a bad idea. VCC will always be > than CTRL pin so the sensor will still have a small positive potential difference. Maybe I should just keep the "source" alternative.

Yes, the sensor datasheet does not specify any start-up time, but I've found out that 5 us gives me good results. I implemented software uart to debug the tiny.

Comment: Per my answer: you should use the GPIO pin as your +VCC supply. Then, correct operation would be to toggle between output high and output tri-state. Definitely stick with the "source" type connection.